# Where should logging be done from a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I currently have my extension writing log data to a file under `context.storagePath`.  This is an approach I modeled after another seeing another extension doing it that way.

However, I have since discovered that [`storagePath` is undefined when you do not have a folder open](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17089#issuecomment-266749537) causing my extension to crash.

That destination being sometimes unavailable makes me think I am not doing logging correctly.  What is the normal or typical logging destination for Visual Studio Code extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a typical logging destination specifically for vscode, but you could use the system's temp folder for that, which is what many applications do. Another good location is the user's home or document dir.